# Why is the "add web service client" bug not fixed in Springsource Tool Suite 3.6.3?

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

When I try to add a web-service-client from a WSDL, I get an error, and to get past this error I have to delete a file called "javax.xml.soap_1.3.0.v201105210645" from the 'plugins' folder.

Here's an original post:

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/springsource-tool-suite/91609-sts-2-5-1-java-io-filenotfoundexception-lib-saaj-jar

Isn't there a way to fix this permanently?

Comment: As mentioned in this issue https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-2072 this was caused by a bug in the Eclipse WTP project, but that bug is fixed a long time ago. Therefore I wonder why this problem seems to be still present. Do you have an error log and some steps how to reproduce this from a fresh STS 3.6.3 installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this again with the latest STS 3.6.3 version and it seems to work just fine. The Eclipse bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=364026 is fixed since quite some time. Please make sure you are using STS on top of the latest Eclipse 4.4 release. The bug in Eclipse Webtools got fixed for Eclipse Luna (4.2), so if you are running STS 3.6.3 on an older Eclipse version, this bug is still there, I would guess. Hope this helps!